# Are Kalman Filter recursions valid when the state noise has a singular covariance matrix?

Tags: kalman-filter, state-space-models, singular-matrix

Consider a Linear Gaussian State-Space Model where the states are denoted by $X_t$ and observations are denoted by $Y_t$:
\begin{align}
X_t &= A X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t, &&\epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, Q) \\
Y_t &= B X_t + \nu_t, &&\nu_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, R)
\end{align}

If we let $\mu_{t|1:t} \equiv \text{E}(X_t | Y_{1:t})$ and $P_{t|1:t} \equiv \text{Var}(X_t | Y_{1:t})$ be the mean and variance of the filtering density at time $t$, respectively, then the Kalman Filter recursions can be expressed as

\begin{align}
\mu_{t|1:t} &= \mu_{t | 1:t-1} + P_{t|1:t-1} B^\top (B P_{t|1:t-1} B^\top + R)^{-1} (y_t - B \mu_{t | 1:t-1}) \tag{1} \\
P_{t|1:t} &= P_{t|1:t-1} - P_{t|1:t-1}B^\top (B P_{t|1:t-1} B^\top + R)^{-1} B P_{t|1:t-1} \tag{2} ,
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
\mu_{t | 1:t-1} &= A \mu_{t-1 | 1:t-1} \\
P_{t|1:t-1} &= A P_{t-1 | 1:t-1} A^\top + Q.
\end{align}

You can see a derivation of these recursion (with a different naming convention being used) in [Lecture 3: Bayesian Optimal Filtering Equations and Kalman Filter by Simo Särkkä](https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/course_k2011/pdf/handout3.pdf)

If $Q$ is a singular matrix, then $Q^{-1}$ does not exist. Furthermore, the density $p(\epsilon_t)$ does not exist, which I believe implies that the density $p(x_t | x_{t-1})$ does not exist. From the lecture notes you will be able to see how this density is needed to obtain the mean and variance of the filtering density.

> Are the Kalman Filter recursions still valid when $Q$ is singular? In other words, given that $Q$ is singular, are equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ the correct representations of the mean and variance of the filtering density?

Please understand that my question is not about whether I can code the recursions and run them successfully. I am asking this from a probabilistic viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many common models feature nonsingular state noise. For example, consider the case of an AR(2) with observational noise. You could set $X_t = (x_t, x_{t-1})^\intercal$ and make your state equation equal to 
$$
\mathbf{x}_t \overset{\text{def}}{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_t \\
x_{t-1}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_1 & \phi_2 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{t-1} \\
x_{t-2}
\end{bmatrix} 
+ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_t\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In this case $Q$ is $2 \times 2$ and has all elements as zero, except for the one in the top left corner.

Whether or not the Kalman filter code will run depends on the invertibility of the one matrix you have to invert. You do not invert the state covariance matrix; rather you invert something has $Q$ added to it. This matrix will usually be invertible because it's positive-definite in most cases.

Regarding your question about densities, you are correct that $p(\mathbf{x}_t \mid \mathbf{x}_{t-1})$ cannot be a density, but $p(x_t \mid x_{t-1}, x_{t-2})$ is.

Regarding your edit, it would probably be better to ask a separate question instead of changing the nature of an existing one so drastically. If densities do not exist, then you would work with measures $(P)$ and [kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel) ($K$). You could replace, for example, this

\begin{align}
p(x_t | y_{1:t-1}) &= \int p(x_t, x_{t-1} | y_{1:t-1}) \; dx_{t-1} \tag{1} \\
&= \int p(x_t | x_{t-1}) p(x_{t-1} | y_{1:t-1}) \; dx_{t-1} \tag{2} 
\end{align}

with this:

\begin{align*}
P(\text{d}x_t  | y_{1:t-1}) &= \int P( \text{d}x_t, \text{d} x_{t-1} | y_{1:t-1}) \\
&= \int K( \text{d}x_t | x_{t-1}) P( \text{d} x_{t-1} | y_{1:t-1}) .
\end{align*}
Note that I'm writing the kernels in a right-to-left way, instead of in the customary, left-to-right way. Following along the AR(2) model, our transition kernel would be written as
$$
K(\text{d} x_t \mid x_{t-1}) = \delta_{x_{t-1}^1}(\text{d}x_t^2 ) p(x_t^1 ; \mu, \sigma^2) \text{d}x_t^1,
$$
where $p(x_t^1 ; \mu, \sigma^2)$ is a normal density, and $\delta$ is the Dirac function that evaluates to either $0$ or $1$, depending on whether $x_{t-1}^1 \in \text{d}x_t^2$.

Comment: I would try to figure out why $Q_t$ is not invertible. The solution provided by Taylor is interesting but a different problem is being solved using his solution procedure. In the case of an AR(2), ( where the noise is a scalar ) his solution works. But, in the general case where the observational equation is not AR and is truly multivariate, a different problem is being solved.

Comment: @mlofton I’m not sure what you mean by “why,” but yes, this small example has only proved it’s not a problem *always*. You would like a set of criteria that would guarantee it’s never a problem. Point taken.

Comment: @Taylor: I understand that the recursions may not directly take the inverse of $Q$. I guess the wording of my question is poor, so my apologies. I am wondering whether the recursions are valid because the density $p(x_t | x_{t-1})$ is necessary, but in the case where $Q$ is singular it doesn't exist. See the edit in the OP.

Comment: @Taylor: I am not familiar with measures and transition kernels, but do we know that the recursions would look the same by using them?

Comment: @Taylor: Regarding my edit, I don't believe it changes the nature of my question, since I am interested in the validity of the recursions given that $Q$ is singular.

Comment: grxxvtny: you're recursions won't run because $Q_t$ can't be inverted. taylor: I meant why in the sense of, if grxxvtony figures out why $Q_t$ is not invertible, then maybe he can take out the variable that is close to linearly dependent with the other one. In fact, thinking about it,  it's not clear to me how $Q_t$ is obtained. sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Taylor: Also, I didn't mean that I wanted a set of criteria that always guarantees that it's never a problem. I was just trying to say that your interesting example may not apply to his case because he probably has a "true" multi-dimensional observational equation.

Comment: @mlofton: I'm not interested in whether the recursions will run, but whether they are valid in the case where $Q$, which is the covariance of the error term in the state equation, is singular.

Comment: @grxxvytony: Then, I'm not clear on what you mean by "valid". If you can't run the KF recusions, then, to me, the system equation variance is not valid. Also, how are you obtaining it ? Usually, it has to be estimated either jointly or before the recursions are run ?

Comment: @mlofton: By "valid" I mean from a probabilistic viewpoint. Given that $Q$ is singular, are the mean and covariance of the filtering density $p(x_t | y_{1:t})$ to be expressed in the same way as we typically see them expressed? See the edit to the OP.

Comment: @grxxvytony: I read your edits  but whether they can be expressed as we typically see them expressed, is still vague to me.  More generally ( outside KF framework ), suppose one has a bivariate normal vector rv, $X_t$, with zero mean and covariance matrix, $Q_t$ that can't be inverted,   Can we still say $X_{t} \sim$ Normal with variance $Q_t$ ? I guess so but it's not helpful. Hopefully someone else can say something more insightful.

Comment: @mlofton: Yes, in that case we can still say that $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, Q_t)$ but $X_t$ does not have a probability density function. Some would call it a degenerate Normal distribution.

Comment: @grxxvytony: Assuming what you're saying is the answer to your question,  then that's a good characterization but this whole thread would have been a lot shorter, if you had just used that terminology ( I've been out of school for a while and maybe my memory is headed south. LOL )  right at the beginning. I like the degenerate characterization but I'm unsure if it's the answer you're looking for or are you still searching ?

Comment: @mlofton: I had just learned it from Wikipedia, lol (Multivariate Normal Distribution, section 3.1.3). It's not term that is in any of the texts I've used in my studies (or in any of the courses I've taken). What I've said is not the answer to my question -- this degenerate characterization is what led to this question.

Comment: @grxxvtony: it's a good characterization but unfortunately, I'm still not clear what you're looking for.  maybe you could think about it more and start a new question and see if someone ( I don't think I can ) can answer ?